# OS X - Rebinding special keys?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I just transferred over from Windows to Mac OS X and it's great, I like it a lot. However, my day job is programming and I'm hungarian - you'll see in a bit why that is important -.
All the alphanumeric characters are on the right place after I've selected the hungarian keyboard layout, however for some reason Apple decided to go total nuts and change the position of all the special characters on the keyboard. As a programmer this is a really big turn off for me, since I have to use special characters all the time.
To give you an idea how big of a change they made:
Regular hungarian keyboard layout: [Link](http://ascii-table.com/img/keyboard-208.png)
OS X hungarian keyboard layout: ... Had to remove the link since I can only post 2 links with such low reputation.

Despite the fact that the OS X special character positions are rather awkward (Alt + Shift + 3 for #, really, Apple?) technically, I could just "get used to them", however, I often have to use non-macintosh computers with the regular HU keyboard layout and switching between that and OS X's HU keyboard layout all the time would be really inconvenient.

Can you guys please help me deciding how to solve this problem? I suppose I should be rebinding my keys using something like Karabiner, but I'm not sure if this is the best/easiest solution.
Thank you in advance. :)

Edit: **Problem solved!** :) I made a custom keyboard layout using Ukelele. If someone else need the layout you can find it here: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/PandaMoniumHUN/Hungarian-Defaults)

Answer (score 2):

Seil and Karibiner also work for this use case:

- https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en
- https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/